# Retrieving phone number when using Twilio Flex

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio Flex, with incoming SMS messages first going through a Studio flow. Specifically, I am querying whether the incoming phone number has texted before (or is a subscriber) by checking it against a CRM database.

However, it looks like Flex sends a hash of the incoming phone number to Studio. So, when I use `{{trigger.message.From}}` I get something like **SMS_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX**.

Is there a way to retrieve the phone number in Studio when using Flex?

The flow otherwise functions as it should without Flex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Studio Flow logs, to see what metadata is sent in to the Studio Flow with the SMS (under Trigger > Widget & Flow Properties > Flow Data).

It looks like the information is in `ChannelAttributes`.

```
ChannelAttributes": {
        "serviceNumber": "sms_gvng1aenviwinstonvtzms9ol91sxxozb",
        "from": "+18025551212",
        "forwarding": true,
        "twilioNumber": "+12055551212",
        "channel_type": "sms",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "long_lived": false,
        "proxySession": "KC92ecfbc962867530975679fff9b2445a"
      }
```

So access it in Studio using:

`{{trigger.message.ChannelAttributes.from}}`